# Why uploading a file is so slow?

Tags: upload

Hi I'm trying to upload a Vae file from pc to Colab drive. The size is only 326 MB, but it took 16 minutes. This is painful, why so slow? Thanks

repeatedly initiate of uploading, at beginning it showed 3hr then it showed 16min

Comment: There are all kinds of things that can happen between your PC and the destination server. Which possibilities have you ruled out through experimentation?

Comment: Paddy thanks for your response. So what should I do to improve the connection to the Colab server? Thanks again :-)

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming and is off-topic here. Troubleshoot your network. It could be anything, including things that are utterly beyond your control. You could be throttled somewhere on your network, by your ISP, by an intermediate router, by the destination server, or the server itself might be under high load. It could even be the communication protocol itself.